# How to extract bold text from a <b> tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I have some (bad) HTML that I'm trying to scrape, which looks like this

```
<div class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify;">
 <span style="font-family: Georgia,&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif;">
 <span style="color: #c00000;">"<i style="mso-bidi-font-style: normal;">Book Name</i>" by 
 <b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;">AUTHOR</b>. Release Date: 
 <b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;">DATE</b>. Published by 
 <b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;">PUBLISHER</b>
</div>
```

I need to extract the three things in bold i.e AUTHOR,DATE & PUBLISHER

I've tried stuff like `$('strong,b').each(...)` but that gives the entire text.

Edit:
Here's the partial code I'm using, basically what I want to do is obtain all the details from a set of such divs.

```
$(".MsoNormal").each(function(index) {

   var book = {}
   var elem = $(this).text()

   elem = sanitizeString(elem) // Removes whitespaces and line breaks

   book["title"] = getTitle(elem) // Gets the book name, which is between double quotes

   //Get author,date & publisher here $('b') traverses everything again

 }
 })
```

Comment: *"that gives the entire text"*. What do you mean? That'll give you each individual element. What is the `...` hiding?

Comment: Well, whatever. You can use `.text()` to get text from an element or a collection of elements. But this is beginner level stuff that you'd learn in your average tutorial. Here's a more intermediate way to do it: `$("b").text(function(i, txt) { console.log(txt); });`

Comment: ...or by *"extract"* do you mean you want to eliminate the wrapping `b` elements and leave the text? In that case `$("b").unwrap()`. You really need to put more effort into describing your issue.

Comment: @squint edited for clarity, sorry for the vagueness

Comment: `// ... here $('b') traverses everything again` So in that case you'd do: `$(this).find("b")...` Please take the time to read a beginner's tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, I will. My JS knowledge is all of 2 hours old, I'm just trying to learn by doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` function like in the example below. `get` method will return an array and then you have the freedom to do whatever you like with that information.

```js
var text = $("b").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

alert(text);
alert("Bold text: " + text.join(" "));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify;">
  <span style="font-family: Georgia,&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif;">
 <span style="color: #c00000;">"<i style="mso-bidi-font-style: normal;">Book Name</i>" by 
 <b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;">AUTHOR</b>. Release Date: 
 <b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;">DATE</b>. Published by 
 <b style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal;">PUBLISHER</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `$('b')` selector:

```
$('b').each(function(index, element) {
    console.log(element.textContent);
});
```

Or if you want to store them in an array you can use the `.map` method:

```
var bold_words = $('b').map(function() { return this.textContent });

console.log(bold_words);
// ["AUTHOR", "DATE", "PUBLISHER"]
```